# Easy Deployment with Github?

Tags: deployment, version-control, github, push, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I searched the web now for several hours but couldn't get around this:

Is there an easy way to deploy a private repository from Github to a staging/development server on each push (or at least manually)? (Best would be if only FTP-data of development server would be needed for this).

I found this: [How can I automatically deploy my app after a git push ( GitHub and node.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js) but this kind of "tutorial" in the best answer stops at the point of what exactly to insert into the build.sh. And what modules are needed for this on the development server? SSH, GIT, Ruby? Maybe this sounds stupid to you, or is a wrong thinking of mine, cause nowhere on the net I found any answer to this.

The problem is, that most time, the server on which the contents of the master branch should be deployed is on a shared hosting server, where you doesn't always have SSH, GIT, Python, Ruby, etc. on which most solutions for deploying from github seem to rely on... :/

http://beanstalkapp.com/ is really great at this, you can just enter FTP-Data and deploy automatically or manually for chosen repositories and branches. So I wondered why I couldn't  find a similar easy way to deploy from Github?

Thank you very much in advance!

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really clear what type of project you have, but here are a couple of ideas.

If your code is written in a compiled language, then you could:

1. Have a Jenkins server as mentioned in the other comment
2. Write a simple script in bash that does a git pull and compile and add a cron job to it.
3. Use an automation framework like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com) which would automatically keep the compiled binary up to date.

If your code is an interpreted language (like HTML & JavaScript), then you could:

1. Use [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) for local testing. The biggest reason is that changes are live on your local system. It only takes a git push on your machine and a git pull on the production server to make your changes live globally.

Your best bet is probably going to be #2.