# Development Workspace and Local Git Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, komodoedit

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 and KomodoEdit for developing NodeJS application.

Also, Im using bitbucket.org for git repository of the application. The repository will have different branches

Is it a good idea to use the local git repository as the workplace for KomoEdit while developing on the application? What is the best way to work on the source code between the workspace and local git repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it a good idea to use the local git repository as the workplace for KomoEdit while developing on the application?

Yes, as long as you don't mix that working tree with deployment.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9132144/6309) is about deploying a node.js app (through a GitHub webhook, but you can adapt it easily [for bitbucket](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webhooks.html#bitbucket).