# Git working tree in mapped windows drive

Tags: windows, git, network-drive

I have a *windows* machine setup with a something like this:

```
N:\path\to\dir\project1.git
N:\path\to\dir\running_dir
```

where `N:` is a **mapped network drive**.

I'm trying to automatically checkout `project1.git` in my `running_dir` upon pushing to `project1.git`. I have followed [this post on exporting GIT_WORK_TREE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js); however, I am confused on what path to use in my `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE= ????????
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

Suppose that `N:` maps to `C:\a\b` on the remote windows machine.

Currently trying: `/c/a/b/path/to/dir/running_dir`

**edit**: Also trying:

```
git --work-tree=/c/a/b/path/to/dir/running_dir checkout -f
```

and getting: `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding absolute paths weren't working - regardless what I tried. Easily fixed by supplying a relative path to `--work-tree` though

Answer (score 0):

Run bash-shell in `N:\path\to\dir\running_dir`, in which perform `pwd`.

Output of this command will be path, translated for bash

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ya I thought of this, it disappointingly yields `/n/path/to/dir/running_dir` (using the git-bash)

Comment: Figured it out (sorta): I added a `pwd > test.txt` line in my `post-receive` and found the output to *still* be `/n/path/to/dir/running_dir`.. which is really weird. However, supplying a relative path to `--work-tree` worked! Put this in an answer and I'll accept ;)