# Deploy application automatically after GitHub push

Tags: php, jenkins, ftp, hudson, travis-ci

**Short version:**
I need to deploy a GitHub repository via FTP to my webspace everytime I push to GitHub.

**Long and boring version:**
I ran into some problems with my current PHP project. I develop locally and tested on the same machine. As I am a new PHP programmer I made every mistake possible. I fixed all of them and it works on my local machine. I then copied it over to a webspace I own and found out that it is not enough to get an application running locally. There were so many errors due to different/hardcoded folders...

I am now searching for a way to automatically deploy my application to my webspace whenever I push to GitHub. I know I could use Jenkins but i do not own a webspace where I can use java applications. I could install it locally but my machine can't connect to anything in the internet other than http/https (corporate proxy), my webspace only offers ftp (I am pushing to GitHub through https). I tried Travis but I am not able to use the ftp command nor am I able to tell curl to copy all (in terms of `*`) of my files at once. I could however use curl to copy one file at a time. But that is in no way feasible.

I tried ftploy. It depoyed the first time really great but all of the commits I did after that where recognized but did not trigger a deployment of the changed files.

Does anyone had the same problem and has a solution to offer?

Thanks for your help,
Alex

Comment: I have used http://dploy.io/ with ftp and it worked well but it was only for a little experiment. It's free for one repo.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automatically deploy my app after a git push ( GitHub and node.js)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js)