# Updating Node JS application after deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

How to update the Application from remote server once it's deployed? Is there any framework available or do we have to write one based on our requirement?

Comment: depends if you are having a git repo then, you need to take the pull and if you are using any deploying tool, you need to check that

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "updating Node JS application"?

Comment: can you make your question a bit more clearer

Comment: @SuryaPurohit, If we are using git repo, pulling the code is only option? What about deployment tools? Can you suggest any such tool?

Comment: @Beginner I am developing a server app based on NodeJS and that app is going to be deployed in remote machines for which I dont have access(not static IP). But they have access to Internet. I would like to know is there any way to update the code/app (features addition and bug fixes)?

Comment: @GunasekaranSrinivasan there's no way to do that if you have no access of the server, unless that server is link to a repo -> nginx

Comment: On the remote server you need to clone your repo and start the server, If you are not having access, how will you do that? There isn't any option then. Furthermore if you are using git, pull the latest code and start ther server agian and  it's deployed :)

Comment: You could use github webhooks to notify jenkins on push and let jenkins do the deploy / testing work for you.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/guides/automating-deployments-to-integrators/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132144/how-can-i-automatically-deploy-my-app-after-a-git-push-github-and-node-js

Comment: @pietrovismara. I think this will suit my requirement.