# adding git tag (version ) info and change history to website

Tags: laravel, tags, commit

I am using Laravel for site development purposes. What would be nice is to have a button on the main page that shows the current version of the project. When clicking on the button, one would see all of the changes that have taken place (in the form of git commits) to the system. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

On click of the button initiate an ajax call

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    url: window.location.origin + '/fetch-git-commits',
    type: "get",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // data contains the git commit informations
        $(".container").html(data);
    }
});
```

In the Route.php file add an entry

```
Route::get('fetch-git-commits', 'YourController@getGitCommits');
```

In the controller

```
public function getGitCommits ()
{
   exec('git log', $output);
   $history = array();

   foreach($output as $line) {
       if(strpos($line, 'commit') === 0) {
           if(!empty($commit)) {
               array_push($history, $commit);   
               unset($commit);
           }
           $commit['hash']   = substr($line, strlen('commit'));
        }
        else if(strpos($line, 'Author') === 0) {
           $commit['author'] = substr($line, strlen('Author:'));
        }
        else if(strpos($line, 'Date') === 0) {
            $commit['date']   = substr($line, strlen('Date:'));
        }
        else {
            if(isset($commit['message']))
                 $commit['message'] .= $line;
            else
                 $commit['message'] = $line;
        }
    }
    return $history; // Array of commits, parse it to json if you need
}
```

References:

[Reading a git commit message from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087883/reading-a-git-commit-message-from-php)

[Parse git log with PHP to an array](https://gist.github.com/geeknam/961488/10bf388491c3757c7266e044bf8d2d6130a49e79)

Comment: Thanks for the info. How can one bring it into Laravel?

Comment: Oh sorry - did not see your entry about Routes.php. Will try this out.

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried the commands you mentioned (at the OS level) and got an interesting response

Comment: : $ git rev-parse --verify HEAD

Comment: 029f8bbdecd21edcfc0dd1568be62b89367a364f

Comment: that's the commit hash

Comment: How would one get the text? I was also hoping to get tags as well. You know - the kind you see when you go to the Wordpress.org site and see the version history of a plugin. There is a tag to note the current version number as well as text to let you know what all was changed in that version.

Comment: Didn't you see the commit message, author and time when you'd executed the command?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little package for that:

https://github.com/tremby/laravel-git-version